# Como ejecutar store procedure en mysql desde laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola muy buenas a toda la comunidad. El motivo de mi pregunta es cómo puedo llamar un procedimiento almacenado en mysql desde laravel.

Código de store procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `votar`(IN identificador INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE total int;
DECLARE incremento int;

SELECT voto INTO total
FROM candidatas WHERE id = identificador;
IF total >= 0 THEN
    SET incremento = total+1;
    UPDATE candidatas SET voto = incremento
    WHERE id = identificador;
END IF;
END
```

Intento llamarlo desde el controlador de esta forma.

```
public function update($id)
{

        if(isset($request['id']))
        {
        //llamando al store procedure
        $id = Input::get('id');
        return DB::select('call votar(?)',array($id));

        }
        return 'votaste';

}
```

En la vista tengo esto:

```
@foreach ($candidatas as $candidata)
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; margin-top:40px;">
                <img style="height:100px; width:110px; background-color:#efefef; margin:20px;" src="/images/{{ $candidata -> foto }}" class="card-img-top rounded-circle mx-auto d-block" alt="">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $candidata -> nombre }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $candidata -> descripcion }}</p>
                    <form action="post" action="/candidata">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="voto" value="{{ $candidata -> id }}">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Votar</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Pero me sale un error 404 y si verifico la tabla no se guardado ningún cambio.

Lo que quiero hacer es que los registros se visualicen en tarjetas de bootstrap. Y que al dar clic en el botón Votar se ejecute un store procedure que tengo en mysql. Supuestamente (digo supuestamente porque no se envía nada) le estoy enviando el id como parámetro al store procedure. Eso mismo hice desde vb.net y funciona.

Comment: Que tal Chalence, verificaste la conexion con la base de datos?

Comment: Si, el mismo store procedure funciona con vb.net. Creo que es un problema con las vistas. También tengo una vista para agregar nuevos registros y funciona muy bien. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es no utilizar la vista edit, porque no la necesito para lo que quiero.

Comment: No me refería al SP o a la base de datos, sino la conexión de laravel, o tu servidor...

Comment: La conexión funciona muy bien, tengo una vista para el ingreso de nuevos registros y funciona muy bien. También me permite visualizar los datos de la base de datos. Pero al hacerlo por medio de store procedure no funciona. En pocas palabras no lo puedo hacer, apenas llevo unos días con el Framework. Por lo que mi experiencia es casi nula.